Novel about a man playing a game who becomes an archmage and uses "death hand" before being teleported into the world by the God of Light
A man is playing a game where he becomes an archmage, a 19th tier mage, and goes to fight the demon king and wins using a spell called Death Hand. After that, he gets teleported to the God of Light who used his last power to teleport him in his world. There was a recap about this book, but I can't find the name of the novel




Are you sure that this is a real novel and not just a tale that some youtuber came up with?

This is posted by the same user as the video in this question.  Valorum's research discovered this: "The person who posted this video specalises in taking Chinese-language, fan-written webnovels from mtlnation.com and shuqi.com. They use an AI tool from a site called Tensor.AI to make generic looking panels for the video. He's also changing the names and some of the character descriptions around." (h/t to Valorum)

As per the channel's intro video:

Our team creates video stories that
won't leave anyone indifferent. First
our script writers create unique stories
that become the basis of our videos then
artists create illustrations to make
your viewing experience as comfortable
and enjoyable as possible.

Intro Video




20 minutes wasted on going through MTLNation Lol.

Some of their stories are not original though

Sorry didn't see that One video also thanks for the help
